# Get a date histogram of occurrences per day

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have a following set of data:

```
{
    "date": "2018-08-28T13:56:29",
    "id": "2db53c87bc701085b7c4eae7efabc247"
},

{
    "date": "2018-08-28T13:57:13",
    "id": "c2c74867e70226096c2a279e89df655d"
},

{
    "date": "2018-08-28T13:58:09",
    "id": "2db53c87bc701085b7c4eae7efabc247"
}
```

I am trying to get a number of event occurrences per day for a given ID over the last month. For example for id `2db53c87bc701085b7c4eae7efabc247` I should get `2`.

I tried the following:

```
{
    sort: {
        date: "desc"
    },
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: {
                term: {
                    "id": "2db53c87bc701085b7c4eae7efabc247"
                }
            },
            filter: {
                range: {
                    date: {
                        gte: "now-1m",
                        lte: "now"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    aggs: {
        daily: {
            date_histogram: {
                field: "date",
                interval: "day"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Elasticsearch gives me the following output:

```
hits: { total: 0, max_score: null, hits: [] },
aggregations: { daily: { buckets: [] } } }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you not using the wrong field in the filter? shouldn't it be date instead of timestamp?

Comment: I've fixed that with no effect on the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently filtering by documents saved in the last minute. You need to change the date filter like this "now-1M"

```
{
    size:0,
    sort: {
        date: "desc"
    },
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: {
                term: {
                    "id": "2db53c87bc701085b7c4eae7efabc247"
                }
            },
            filter: {
                range: {
                    date: {
                        gte: "now-1M",
                        lte: "now"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    aggs: {
        daily: {
            date_histogram: {
                field: "date",
                interval: "day"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fran, that worked. However in the response I am getting the whole document instead of just count (int). Any idea how to change that?

Comment: I have updated my answer, basically, you need to pass the size:0